# can a comment be transfered to academia.se?

Tags: discussion

[This soft question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54825/i-was-rejected-from-my-dream-graduate-school-what-should-i-do) was migrated to academia.SE. As a result, comments are impossible at physics.se, and  I find comments to my answer that are  alerting me, but I cannot reply to them . I emphatically do not want to register on another site and I see that the questioner also cannot act there unless he/she registers. This is quite annoying and unnecessary for such a simple question. And I do not agree that this is a general question for academia. It is different for lawyers, for example, and all the money gathering disciplines.

Anyway:

Can somebody who is registered there add to the citation request  for my statement that "most original ideas come before the age of thirty",

the names of Newton, Maxwell and Feynman , as a start ?. This series of biographies of physicists also supports my statement: http://www.phy.pmf.unizg.hr/~dpaar/fizicari/index.html

Comment: Dear Anna, I have left a corresponding comment below your answer including a link to this meta question.

Comment: Thanks Dilaton, that is good.

Comment: I don't see the reason for a downvote here...

Answer (score 1):

> and I find comments to my answer that are alerting me, but I cannot reply to them

I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be happening, as the system no longer "knows" it was you who posted that answer. You'll still get notifications for comments made on your answer before it was migrated, but that should be all.

Anyway, if you consider it annoying to have to register on another site to comment there, you can do that, but it *is* necessary. The alternative is either allowing unregistered users to comment, which is intentionally not the case for obvious reasons, or unifying the account system for all SE sites so that anyone with an account on one of them automatically has an account on all, which was a (reasonable IMO) design decision on the part of the SE team. Comments cannot be migrated, of course.

As for whether it's a general question for academia, that's up to the Academia.SE community to figure out. What we know is that it is not a question for this site.

Comment: well , it does alert me. I would not have noticed their comments if no alerts were coming. I got one this morning too, a rude one.

Comment: @annav Wow, I dont know what has happend. I have just seen this offensive comment, flagged it as offensive, and it has immediately disappeared ...

Comment: @Dilaton .  Thanks for flagging it .The continuous upvote of the requests for citations is one of the reasons that this question belongs to physics.se and not to academia. It is a well known observation for physics and no thesis is necessary . In the biographies list most of them have their crucial research at an age below thirty.I expected Maria Curie to be over thirty (due to family obligations) but she also made her crucial observations before thirty. –

Comment: @annav I agree that the question should have been kept here and left open. As Lurscher said in a now deleted comment to the migrated soft question, we have not enough people who bother to state reopen votes ... There are some good people who used to ask very good and interesting theoretical questions who I suspect have a more reasonable attitude concerning certain things (than people heavily close-voting since last december), but since they rather ask than answer they have not enough power (rep) to cast reopen votes :-/